# Highchart loading csv with 2 values

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I’m having a litte problem with Highcharts probably because I’m a total noob with Javascript.

With Highcharts I want a chart that shows date on the x-axis and the value on the y-axis. I’m using a CSV file (`results.csv`) that looks like this:

```
821,2013-11-12
1623,2013-11-13
```

… and so on.

I used the Highchart documentation on preprocessing CSV data, and the example on the website.
I made a website with 4 different charts and 4 CSV files, but all those files were made by myself using the same layout as the example on highchart. Now I want to use other CSV files.

My code looks like this:

```
$.get('./results.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');

        // header line containes categories
        if (lineNo == 0) {
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
            });
        }

        // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
        else {
            var series = {
              data: []
            };
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo == 0) {
                    series.name = item;
                } else {
                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                }
            });

            options.series.push(series);

        }

    });

    var chart4 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yELdd/)

I’m stuck.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: On the x-axis i only see the first value of the csv (2013-11-12) and the chart itself is empty. The legend below the chart shows the values (821,1623) Thanks for your reply

Comment: In the jsfiddle you cannot load a csv file. How you full csv looks like?

Comment: Hi Sebiastian thanks for the reply i posted my csv to pastebin:http://pastebin.com/VQC0vN5n, the first value must be my y-axis and the second must be on the x-axis. Thanks a lot for your time